# Maximum weight bipartite matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching, bipartite

I have a graph in form of a rectangular grid, i.e. N nodes and 2N edges, all adjacent nodes are connected.
This means it is two-colourable, and hence it is possible to do bipartite matching on it.

Each (undirected) edge has a weight assigned to it - either -2, -1, 0, 1 or 2. No other values are allowed

How would I go about finding the matching on this graph that maximises the sum of the weighs in the matching? Pseudocode would be nice, don't bother with specific languages.

Ideally, I am looking for an algorithm that runs in quadratic time - maybe O(n^2 log n) at worst.

---

Before you propose a solution, I have tried doing a max match using edges of weight 2, then of weight 1 (without going over edges of weight 2). I have scored 98% with this implementation (the problem is from an informatics olympiad), and wondering what is the 100% solution.

Comment: Don't you mean 2N edges? And you want the matching to include all nodes, correct?

Comment: Yes, 2N edges (edited to reflect that). And I want the matching to include any number of nodes, as long as the sum of the edges in the matching is maximised.

Comment: I think you are looking for graph cuts - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory). The minimum cut algorithm runs O(n^3) though and I doubt anyone here will beat that.

Comment: @dark_charlie: Why do you say that it will be O(n^3)? Currently, I am thinking of Ford-Fulkerson, which is O(VE), or in my case O(n^2). The only problem is that it is icky to implement.

Comment: @Evgeny: Ford-Fulkerson is O(V * E^2) where E^2 = 4 * V^2 in your case and that yields O(V^3).

Comment: @dark_charlie: Sorry, I meant that ford-fulk implemented as O(Ef) will actually be O(EV) in this case. As f is approximately equal to E, that yields O(n^2).

Comment: capacities can not be negative to apply min cut, otherwise max cut is min cut with reversed sign weights, and it's an NP-complete problem

Comment: This problem reminds me of ground state in spin glasses, not sure exactly which variant. If you could put your hands on it, I would check this paper http://iopscience.iop.org/0305-4470/15/10/028 A node beloning to a partition maps to the spin state, and the weight of an edge is the strength of the interaction, and the sign tells if it is repulsive or attractive and max weight can be mapped (reversing the weights I suppose) to finding the ground state. That paper has both positive and negative results for different versions of this model and one might map to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you are thinking of min cut.  A cut  is not guaranteed to give you matching in this case. What you need to do is solve assignment problem.[Assignment Problem](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/07assignment.pdf). The successive shortest math algorithm solves it in O(EV log V) which in your case is O(n^2 log n).